# Redshift SQL to remove text after a space

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to remove the text after space from the below example (the name of the data field is model

R17245 20 should return just R17245

FG789 32 should return just FG789...

**Query tried**

```
Select regex_replace(model,'','')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the logic here is to remove everything from the first space onwards, you may use:

```sql
SELECT model, REGEXP_REPLACE(model, ' .*$', '') AS model_out
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Thank you so mcu @Tim Biegeleisen...Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can split your input string on ' ' and then take the first part. Sample code (Redshift) :

```
SELECT model, SPLIT_PART (model, ' ', 1) as model_processed 
FROM yourTable;
```

Documentation link : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/SPLIT_PART.html